# Captura do Evento de Impressão

Tags: c#

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber como faço para capturar o evento de impressão usando c#.

Exemplo: o usuário clica na opção de imprimir da aplicativo que ele estiver usando(Word, outlook etc...) e ao invés de chamar uma impressora o abriria um form, que irei desenvolver.

Pois quero tratar as informações, grava-las em um banco e enviar essa impressão a um servidor.

Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que seja isto o que procura [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162722(v=vs.85).aspx)

Sintaxe C++:

```
HANDLE FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(
  _In_      HANDLE hPrinter,
  DWORD fdwFilter,
  DWORD fdwOptions,
  _In_opt_  LPVOID pPrinterNotifyOptions
);
```

Uso da DLL:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv",
    EntryPoint = "FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification",
    ...)]
```

Um exemplo de uso:

[Monitor jobs in a printer queue (.NET)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET)

<sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229892/1518921</sub>